# How can i make an onclick box have multiple functions and display a different message each time?

Tags: html, css, onclick

So I'm in the middle of making a neocities page, and I'd like to be creative with introducing myself on my page, i saw on this website (https://y2k.neocities.org/salem.html) that there's an onclick button which displays a DIFFERENT message each time it is clicked. what i'd like is it for to do just that, NOT display multiple messages at once (or display previous messages as well). any help on how i can achieve this is appreciated, ive been trying to achieve this but wherever i search doesnt have the same thing i want.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more as from where the messages will come, any specific list of items like array of 40 items which contain messages and from that array message will be displayed randomly?

Comment: i'd like for the messages to just come from the button but not exactly, displayed like an array. it'd display a random message each time that button was clicked, i hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can use type onclick = "function1() ; function2()" to show different message once

but if you want to have a random message per click you should create an array then you must add Random to it Here is code:

```js
var arr = ["Text1","Text2","Text3"];
function display(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="display()">Click</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes this is what i meant thank you!!